# How to convert img tag to image preview in active admin

Tags: image, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, formtastic

In Active Admin I have a show page which is as follows:

```
show do |page|
    attributes_table do
      rows :id, :name
    end

    panel 'Sections' do
      attributes_table_for page.sections do
        rows :section, :content, :priority
      end
    end
    active_admin_comments
  end
```

The 'content' field in the above code can have html 'img' tag OR just some text content. If it contains img tag, I want to display the preview image of the image. I dont know how I can achieve this in Active Admin. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
panel 'Sections' do
  attributes_table_for page.sections do
    row :section
    row :content do
       if page.content.includes? '<img'
         image_tag :content
       else
         :content
       end
    end
    row :priority
  end
end
```

Or some similar.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
panel 'Sections' do
      attributes_table_for page.sections do
        row :section
        row :content do |section|
          section.content.html_safe
        end
        row :priority
      end
    end
    active_admin_comments
  end
```